# Setting value for javascript variable from code behind (C#)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I understand the difference between Client-side and Server-side scripting. I have a javascript function and variable in my `MasterPage`:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var needToConfirm = false;
          window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
          function confirmExit()
          {
            if (needToConfirm)
            {
              needToConfirm = false;
              return "Currently in edit mode. If you leave the page now then you will lose unsaved changes."
            }
          }
</script>
```

Given the fact that on my ASP.NET (Client-side) I can change the value of my `needToConfirm` variable to `true` `onClientClick` but by default it is false. Here's an example.

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="  Edit  " onclick="btnEdit_Click" OnClientClick="needToConfirm = true;" />
```

Now the question here is when on the C# (Server-side) I have to set the `needToConfirm` to true under an `if-statement` but not necessarily on `Page_Load`:

```
private void SetDefault()

    if (Session[def.ID_CUST] != null)
    {
          //I want to change the variable value here
    }
}
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I'm using .NET 2.0 Classic and WebForms

Comment: Direct call of script from server-side are impossible. However you can use of ClientScript.RegisterStartup() script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in code behind:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "urFunction('urValHere');", true);
```

on client-side:

```
function urFunction(urParam) {
        //do what u want here
        //use urParam
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use a hidden input and then set this input to `true` or `false` from the server side.

On the client side:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnConfirm" runat="server" value="false"/>
```

Then on the server side:

```
 if (Session[def.ID_CUST] != null)
    {
          //I want to change the variable value here
           hdnConfirm.Value = "true";
    }
```

Then on the client side:

```
var needToConfirm = $('#hdnConfirm').val();
```

Comment: can you elaborate it more. or put some details (code sample)?

Comment: var needToConfirm = false;
use this.
var needToConfirm = $('#hdnValue').val();
just set the value of hdnValue in codebehind

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, you could register a client script like in the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx.

```
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(this.GetType(), "EditMode")) {
    cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "EditMode", "needToConfirm = true;", true);
}
```

That would write a script to the page setting the value of `needToConfirm` in Javascript.

Comment: It worked for the `Page_Load` but how about when in a separate method in C#?

Comment: Should work the say way in any method that inherits `System.Web.UI.Page`. Button clicks, postbacks, etc, etc.

Comment: yes but I don't actually need to trigger the variable change on Button Clicks and postbacks. Thanks though.

Comment: Right, I was just using those as possible methods that could be used. You could use them in any method within the class.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your update saying it's .NET 2.0, this is how you can set a javascript variable:

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("SetVar", "var needToConfirm = true;");
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference.  Here is the 4.5 way to do something like this:

```
 // Define the name and type of the client scripts on the page.
 const String csname1 = "MyScriptName";
 Type cstype = this.GetType();

 // Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
 ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

 // Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
 if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csname1))
 {
      StringBuilder cstext1 = new StringBuilder();
      cstext1.Append("<script> var myVariable = true; </");
      cstext1.Append("script>");

      cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname1, cstext1.ToString());
  }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Maby this helps?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(confirm){
        var needToConfirm = confirm;
        window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
        function confirmExit() {
            if (needToConfirm) {
                needToConfirm = false;
                return "Currently in edit mode. If you leave the page now then you will lose unsaved changes."
            }
        }
    }
</script>



<asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" onclick="btnEdit_Click" OnClientClick="javascript:test(true);" />
```