How to set global JS variable from C# in website
Just learning/diving into a cshtml and razor application so please bear with.
We have an MVC razor front end UI application which calls a C# API back end application.
Currently the URL for the API is set in one of the js files, example apiCalls.js
This file is then added as a reference to the bottom of the page1.cshtml page with:
@Html.Script(Url.WidgetContent("~/Custom/Scripts/apiCalls.js"), "bottom")
This all works fine, and an AJAX call is made on the apiCalls.js page to retrieve data from the API.
However, I would like the API url to be set in the C# side, currently it is set in the apiCalls.js, and used when needed for AJAX
I have found a few similiar topics:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/671106/How-can-i-declare-global-variable-to-use-all-mvc-v
and the accepted answer here:
Access Session variables in JavaScript
but it isnt working.
So in global.asx.cs I am adding:
private void PagePreRenderCompleteEvent(IPagePreRenderCompleteEvent evt)
{
HttpContext Context = HttpContext.Current;
if (Context != null && Context.Session != null)
{
   Session["apiURL"] = "https://www.123.com";
}
}

then at the top of apiCalls.js I am replacing the current
var api = 'www.api123.com';

with
console.log('api START');

var api = '@Session["apiURL"]';

console.log('apiEndPoint END ' + api);

but I can see from the comments in the console that:
apiEndPoint START
apiEndPoint END @Session["apiURL"]

obviously this is because its a string, but why is the accepted answer I mentioned like so:

what am I missing please?
Thanks for any replies

use cookie, OR: you can do in configuration  json set application variable. OR on application start Application["variablename"] = "hello"; and to read: HttpContext.Application["variablename"].ToString();

i think this thread would be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624242/how-can-i-set-a-global-variable-in-razor-pages-of-asp-net-core

Hi thanks for reply, yes setting or declaring the value in #C is ok but how do I retrieve it in the js file when I need it?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474640/setting-value-for-javascript-variable-from-code-behind-c
